# Encode Letters using m-ary Huffman Encoding

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given that we have the following letters frequencies:

$$A: 0.25, E: 0.30, N: 0.10, R: 0.05, T: 0.12, Z: 0.18$$

And we have a 3-ary Huffman encoding tree, so labels are from 0 to 2 (edge could be labelled with 0, 1, or 2). Now, I will show the first two steps only as this is where I would like to ask the question.

**Step 1**: we select the first **two vertices** with the least frequencies, which are $R, N$, and put them into a single tree.

[image]

**Step 2**: we then select the three trees with the smallest labels: $T, N+R, Z$,

[image]

**Question**: since we label edges from 0 to 2 (0, 1, or 2), we should select 3 trees in each step as I understand. Why in step 1 do we select only 2 trees while in step 2 do we select 3 trees, please?

Comment: I think you should be selecting 3 trees, not 2, even in step 1. Why are you only selecting 2? I would have selected N, R and T to merge, not just N and R.  Any reason why you went with 2?

Comment: @StefanLafon. Thank you. That's the book solution.

Comment: Note: I could be wrong, as I haven't played with Huffman in years. Plus I usually deal with binary trees :) Question: You could compute the entropy for both encodings and see which one leads to the smallest entropy. The smallest one is the Huffman encoding.

Comment: By entropy, I mean expected codelength.

Comment: @StefanLafon. Thanks. Is there another way to do it please as this is not covered in the text?